# How to write Polish character from JOSON file to JSON file?

Tags: python, json, encoding

I tried:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
with open("File1", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump( {"Tytuł":"tą"}, outfile, indent = True, encoding="utf-8")
```

Which gives me:

```
{
"Tytu\u0142": "t\u0105"
}
```

What'd I like to get is:

```
{
"Tytuł": "tą"
}
```

---

`ensure_ascii=False` works, but when  I try to get JSON data from the file, I get `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters...`

The code I'm using for this is:

```
json_data=open('File0')
data = json.load(json_data)
with open("File1", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump( data,outfile,indent = True,ensure_ascii=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting argument `ensure_ascii` to False:

```
with open("File1", "w") as outfile:
    json.dump( {"Tytuł":"tą"}, outfile, indent = True, encoding="utf-8", ensure_ascii=False)
```